# Sites not accepting wget user agent header

Tags: http, wget, user-agent

When I run this command:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"  http://yahoo.com
```

...I get this result (with nothing else in the file):

```
<!-- hw147.fp.gq1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Jun 19 03:42:44 UTC 2013 -->
```

But when I run `wget http://yahoo.com` with no `--user-agent` option, I get the full page.

The user agent is the same header that my current browser sends. Why does this happen? Is there a way to make sure the user agent doesn't get blocked when using wget?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It seems Yahoo server does some heuristic based on `User-Agent` in a case `Accept` header is set to `*/*`.

> Accept: text/html

did the trick for me.

e.g.

```
wget  --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"  http://yahoo.com
```

Note: if you don't declare `Accept` header then `wget` automatically adds `Accept:*/*` which means give me anything you have.

Comment: It isn't just Yahoo that filter out requests like this - Something to always be aware of!

Comment: Edit your `~/.bash_profile` by adding `alias mwget='wget --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"'` so you don't have to deal with the params each time.

Answer (score 37):

I created a `~/.wgetrc` file with the following content (obtained from [askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/linux/wget-header-trick.html) but with a newer user agent, because otherwise it didn’t work always):

```
header = Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
header = Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
header = Connection: keep-alive
user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
referer = /
robots = off
```

Now I’m able to download from most (all?) file-sharing (streaming video) sites.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set both the user-agent and the referer:

```
 wget  --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" --referer  connect.wso2.com http://dist.wso2.org/products/carbon/4.2.0/wso2carbon-4.2.0.zip
```