# Automated login attempt gives status code 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, authentication, automation

I'm trying to auto login into an HTML form that has some jQuery attached to it. I want to log in from the command line (`wget`). In order to do that, I first tried to find out what happens when I submit the form. Firefox tells me that the following piece of code gets executed on submit:

```
function(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault(), StartPage.auth.busy) return false;
  StartPage.auth.busy = true;
  var form = $("#login_form"),
    user = form.find("input[name=username]").val(),
    p = form.find("input[name=password]").val(),
    rem = $("#remember-me").is(":checked");
  $.post(StartPage.uris.auth, {
    username: user,
    password: p,
    remember: rem ? 1 : 0
  }, function(e) {
    return e.error ? false : void document.location.reload()
  })
}
```

It looks to me, as though it does some validatio first, and then posts the contents to `StartPage.uris.auth`, which is always `/page/auth`.

Now, when I try to do that manually:

```
$ wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data='username=user&password=pass&remember=1' --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0' "https://www.website.com/page/auth"
```

it just gives me a status code 500. Peculiarly, if my password is *not* correct, it answers with a proper HTML page that says "user or password not correct". I know that 500 is practically impossible to debug, since it's not my fault that it happened. However, how can this even occur? When I send a POST request using `wget`, am I not doing the *exact* same thing as that jQuery snippet does? I also tried to fabricate the request in Firefox and got the same result, so cookies are no issue.

When I do

```
$.post(StartPage.uris.auth, {
    username: "user",
    password: "pass",
    remember: 1
  }, function(e) {
    return e.error ? !1 : void document.location.reload()
  })
```

from the Firefox javascript console, everything works just fine.

Comment: Try adding the protocol to the url of your `wget` command. Also, if the url ends with a trailing `/` as you said, make sure you have the exact same url in your command. Then, if your username and password contain special characters, make sure you url_encode those (eg: a space would become `%20`). If it still doesn't work, log in on the site with your _network_ tab open, look at the request headers, and try to replicate some of those and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @blex Adding the protocol gives me the same thing, unfortunately. And the trailing slash is my typo, sorry about that. The password and username are both just ASCII, I actually took extra care of that ;). I'll take a look into the request headers, thanks! Although, shouldn't these be correct when I fire the request from within Firefox? The way I do it, I go to the network tab and then edit a GET request by changing its type to POST and adding the Content-Type and Content-Length arguements and finally adding the body. Is there something else missing there?

Comment: Unfortunately, as it is, I can't tell :( As you said, getting a plain error 500 is not very helpful

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182553/sites-not-accepting-wget-user-agent-header - and check your request headers against that.

Comment: @blex @RobinMackenzie You were right, turns out it was the headers. Executing the jquery snippet gives me another header that I need to add to wget as a flag: `--header="X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"`. Does one of you want to write up a full answer, so I can accept it? I could also write one myself of course. I'm not sure which is preferred.

Comment: Awesome! We were just guessing, but since you found the exact cause, you can write the answer yourself and accept it